# looking for faster eigen alternatives to this loop

Tags: c++, eigen

I often have to use a loop such as:

```
//Preparing a self contained example:
int m=10,n1=2*m,n2=4*m;
VectorXf a3=VectorXf::Random(n2);
VectorXf x(n1); 
VectorXi iS(m);

for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
  iS(i)=rand()%n2;

std::cout << "old x" << std::endl;
std::cout << x(0) << std::endl;
//this is the loop I want to find a better alternative to:
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
  x(i)=a3(iS(i));

std::cout << "new x" << std::endl;
std::cout << x(0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "same as" << std::endl;
std::cout << a3(iS(0)) << std::endl;
```

I was wondering whether there is a better way to do this loop 
--the one with  `x(i)=a3(iS(i))`-- using eigen.

**EDIT**: to make the question more clear, I've completed the example.

Comment: If this were `numpy`, it'd be as simple as `x = a3[iS]` (or `x[:] = a3[iS]` for copying into the existing `x` array), but I'm not sure what the equivalent syntax is in eigen. I'm sure there's some similar syntax, though.

Comment: thanks for giving me hope JAB

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing so (which is both cleaner and faster) is to use [Eigen::Map](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html). You can simply do like this:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi>x(iS.data(),iS.size());
```

You can use the same syntax for arrays as well.

#### Edit:

After question update by OP:

In a general case when you want to assign part of an `Eigen` object (e.g. a matrix) to another Eigen object, you can use [block](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) operations:

as an example:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf m(4,4);
    m << 1 , 2 , 3 ,  4,
         5 , 6 , 7 ,  8,
         9 , 10, 11, 12,
         13, 14, 15, 16;
cout<<m.block<2,2>(0,1)<<std::endl;
```

prints

```
5 , 6 
9 , 10
```

You can use this syntax for assigning as well:

```
//Block of size (p,q), starting at (i,j)
matrix.block<p,q>(i,j) = another matrix.block<p,q>(k,l)
```

For your particular problem that your data is not sequentially stored (i.e. having an random index vector), I'm afraid your loop is as good as it gets. You may find something in *igl* [here](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/libigl/) and [here](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/libigl/matlab-to-eigen.html) or in [mrpt](http://www.mrpt.org/) project. They have a [plugin](http://reference.mrpt.org/svn/eigen__plugins_8h.html) for eigen.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand: you seem to have no reference to 'a3' in your code~

Comment: Actually I failed to understand your question completely and my answer is for general cases. In my answer, you initialize an Eigen::Vector `x` with the values stored in a std::vector `iS`. Am I missing something here? Let me know and I will update the answer `:)`.

Comment: OK. I have completed the example to make it more clear what I meant. You see, I want to copy *some* elements of a3 into the first m entries of x.

Comment: @user189035, I see what you need. I'm going to update the answer but I'm afraid it will not solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer...but you can see it's not going to answer my question (the destination is contiguous but the source is not)